# How do I setup Rails dynamic segments across the routes, controller and view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models called `Album` and `Photo`.  I want the url to edit a photo to be in this format:

```
/photos/:album_id/:photo_id/edit/

/photos/5/2/edit/
```

where:

```
album_id = 5
photo_id = 2
```

How do I set the above across the route, controller and view?

Comment: A little lacking in information. Post your current routes.rb at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically need it in the format you specified, it is Rails convention to use the URL format of:

```
/albums/:album_id/photos/:id
```

And in your routes you will have :

```
resources :albums do
   resources :photos
end
```

Then you can use in your Photos controller

```
def show
   album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
   @photo = album.photos.find(params[:id])
end
```